# C array of vector_float2* in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How do I make a C array of `vector_float2*'? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. If you can create the array in C, you know how to do it in Objective-C since it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know:

```
// simple C array: type identifier[] = {value,value,...};
// example:        int  myIntegers[] = {1,2,3};
// Note that specifying the size is optional.

// example of a vector_float2 value: vector_float2 myVector = {1.0,1.0};

// array of 9 (3x3) vector_float2 values:
vector_float2 myVectors[] = {
    {0.0,0.0},{0.5,0.0},{1.0,0.0},
    {0.0,0.5},{0.5,0.5},{1.0,0.5},
    {0.0,1.0},{0.5,1.0},{1.0,1.0}
};

// Note that  vector_float2 *  and  vector_float2 []  are interchangeable:
vector_float2 * vectors = myVectors

vector_float2 aVector = vectors[4];
printf("vector x:%f y:%f\n",aVector.x,aVector.y);
```